# DEBUGGING: Code logs "undefined" when JSON is called with a variable

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, undefined

I have written in **javascript** something similar to the following, and I will try to reproduce my problem:

```
this.showInfo = function() {
  var t = "";
  var temp_family = query.t_family.toString();
  var temp_category = query.t_category;
  var temp_subcategory = query.t_subcategory;
  $.getJSON("../javascript/stock.json", function(json) {

    console.log("Good luck! JSON: ", json[temp_family], query.t_family.toString());

  });
}
```

where **query** is a (dinamic??) object.

The issue is that when I log in the console the result from `json[temp_family]`, logs **undefined**. But when I log `query.t_family.toString()` or simply `json[{some_random_property}]` (with a string of a property on the JSON file) it does log what I would expect...

What is my error here?

Comment: Please provide example JSON used.

Comment: What is the value you get from `query.t_family.toString()` ?

Comment: I will edit and add answers for that.